# How to make UIView transparent

Tags: uiview

I am a iOS newbie. I don't know how to make UIView transparent. Please give me instructors (It's good if having code sample ).
Example:

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view setTransparent];
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can either set the background color to clear:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

This will only make the background transparent (so if you have any subviews they will still be visible).

Or you could set the alpha property to 0:

```
view.alpha = 0
```

This will make not only that view transparent, but also any subviews also.

Answer (score 1):

```
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
```

try this